# taglibs-standard-impl vs jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib

I need to replace jstl library from my project due to some vulnerabilities it presents.
However my project makes use of jsps and tags like  and I need a replacement. 
Can I just replace

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>jstl</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `XML External Entity (XXE) Injection` vulnerability was already fixed in 1.2.3 version of `taglibs-standard-impl`.